# Total monthly hours worked based on criteria

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-10

I'm using laravel 10 and I have a working code, count of each operator of each day and month the total time spent. Now I would like to create a monthly total count instead of a daily one but I have not yet managed to modify correctly to make it work, I would like to display the monthly hourly count of each operator and how many tickets are where this operator appears. Does anyone know how to help me? This is the code in the blade file

```
<tbody>
 @foreach($response as $value)
  @foreach($value as $val)
   <tr>
    <td>
      @php
       $date = strtotime($val['date_logs']);
       $dat = date('m-Y', $date);
      @endphp
       {{ $dat }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ $val['operator_name'] }}</td>
       @if($val['time_spent'] !=0)
        @php
         $val['time_spent'] = $val['time_spent']*60;
         $minsec = gmdate("i:s", $val['time_spent']);
         $hours = (gmdate("d", $val['time_spent'])-1)*24 + gmdate("H", $val['time_spent']);
         $totalHours =  $hours.':'.$minsec;
        @endphp
        @else
        @php
         $totalHours =0;
        @endphp
       @endif
       <td>{{ $totalHours }}</td>
       <td>{{ $val['ticket_no'] }}</td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: `but I have not yet managed to modify correctly to make it work` Please tell us what doesn't work. Do you get an error, wrong values or nothing?

Comment: No, the daily count is correct and works, I can't do a monthly count, I would like to do a monthly count of the hours of each operator and the ticket_nos that the operator has managed, now I only see the count of hours but by day

Comment: And why "can`t" you do a monthly count?

Comment: I didn't succeed and I'm asking for help, I now only see it daily but I haven't yet managed to see it total by month

Comment: And where should we get the data from to calculate the time per month? Just adding up the time per day for all days in the month?

Comment: yes, I have already created the code for the daily calculation in the controller, maybe I should rewrite that because it is not possible in the blade file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256352/discussion-between-arco-and-marco).

Comment: Can you help me understand how to do it?